# Magento Redesigning blog page, post content div

Tags: magento, blogs

I want to redesign the post content in "aheadWorks Extensions" I installed in Magento to make the image on the right and the post contents on the left.

I already found the line that responsible for this in "blog.phtml" and that it is:

```
<div class="postContent"><?php echo $post->getPostContent(); ?></div>
```

so where is the source file for this line so I can redesign the divs and image size etc...

I need a way to add images in the post and these images should be set exactly in the position I want it in the post contents area.

OR can I delete `<?php echo $post->getPostContent(); ?>` and make different design? or can I edit the backend to add new field for adding images in the right position, actually I am looking for open source code

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can style by using external css file. why you need that source code?

Comment: Hi DRAJI, I need that because I need to add images to the left by default not by editing the content area at admin blog area, actually to be precised, I need a way to add images in the post.and these images should be set exactly in the position I want it in the post contents area, I hope I was clear, Thank you

Comment: can you post url of your extension ?

Comment: Here is the extension url: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blog-community-edition-by-aheadworks.html thank you Keyur

Comment: <?php echo $post->getPostContent(); ?> it means what will you write in backend

Comment: can I delete <?php echo $post->getPostContent(); ?> and make different design? or can I edit the backend to add new field for adding images in the right position, actually I am looking for open source code